# input element has no readonly attribute but the fields are still uneditable

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, json, dom

I'm creating a form in React and I have `<input>` fields that get populated from server data. The fields are supposed to show the user what's currently there and also allow them to edit the data when they submit the form. However, when I try to type in the input fields, nothing happens. The text is selectable but unchangeable.

Could this be because I populated the fields with data stored in state variables and therefore it keeps a perpetual value of what it's getting from the server?

This portion of code is the function responsible for reading the server data and setting the state variables that are then passed to the *Form* component.

```
const [templateId, setTemplateId] = useState("");
const [templateData, setTemplateData] = useState([]);

function mkForm(selection) {
    if(selection !== "newTemplate"){
        fetch(`http://localhost:3000/custom/${selection}`)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data)=>{
            setTemplateId(data.id)
            setTemplateData(Object.entries(data.myData));
        })
    } else{
        setTemplateId("");
        setTemplateData([]);
    }
}
```

This is the *Form* component that receives the props, this portion is only showing the code creating the input fields from the *templateData* prop. The *templateId* input field is being returned in the component's main return statement but it's pretty much the same.

```
function Form({templateId, templateData}) {
    const showData = templateData.map((item)=>{
        return(
            <div onChange={foo}>
                <input value={item[0]}/> <input value={item[1]} />
            </div>
        )
   })
   ... etc.
   ... etc.
}
```

I changed some variable names to show the related state variables and props.

I may be misunderstanding what "debugging" means, but I don't think there is any debugging information to share as my issue doesn't throw any errors. Everything does what it's supposed to, data is pulled from the server and populates the input field. The issue is that new text wasn't appearing as I typed into it, leading me to believe that the value never changed. The problem seemed to have been with my understanding of the "value" attribute of an `<input>` tag. I expected the "value" attribute to behave like a default value which could be updated as I typed into the input field (which it did) but I also expected the input field to always reflect that value, which it did not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set `value` field of an `input` field in React, the `input` field will always keep that value, so for you, it'll appear as if it's uneditable.

There are two potential solutions.

##### Use `defaultValue`

If you're fine with not using the changed value of the input field:

```
<input defaultValue={someValue} />
```

See [Uncontrolled Components](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html) for more details.

##### Add `onChange` event

Most likely, you'll want to use the value that you edited, so in that case:

```
<input value={someValue} onChange={handleChange} />
```

In this case, your `handleChange` method needs to be written so that it updates your `value` upon change.

See [Controlled Components](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) for reference.

Comment: But the value never changes since I can't type into the field so the onChange function never triggers.

Comment: As I said, it _does_ trigger, it just doesn't update the input field because there's a fixed `value` fed into it. As long as you change `value` in the `onChange` handler, you'll see the change.